# Java Eclipse Maven called from a .bat: null pointer and no main class attribute in manifest errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This is driving me crazy. I have a project set up with maven (first time I use it) on Eclipse. It consists of several classes simulating a Music Player. Its main its suppossed to recieve 3 arguments: a .tsv tunes file, a .tsv "operations" (commands to test the program's output) folder and an integer to set max number of songs in a queue. When I run everything as a JUnit test, simulating the calls that main does it works just fine (no exceptions) but when I use the external .bat that actually tries to call the .jar package and give it the parameters I get this error:

[image: cmd error]

I think the first problem is that i don't have a Main Class specified in Maven pom. But still, it looks like Main.java is actually being called and gives a nullPointerException. This is Main's code:

```
package es.uned.lsi.eped.pract2016_2017;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        /* 
          leer argumentos: 
            numero máximo de canciones recientemente escuchadas (arg[0]),
            fichero del repositorio de canciones (arg[1]),
            fichero de operaciones (arg[2]).
         */     
        //String pathTunes = args[0];
        String pathOperations = args[1];
        int maxRecentlyPlayed = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
        //Creación de TunesCollection       
        TuneCollection tCollection = new TuneCollection("src/main/resource/Repository.tsv");        
        //Creación de Player
        Player player = new Player(tCollection,maxRecentlyPlayed);
        //Número de canciones del repositorio
        System.out.println(tCollection.size());
        //Lectura del fichero de operaciones
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathOperations), "UTF-8"));
        //Ejecución de las operaciones en el orden recibido
        String operation;
        while ((operation = in.readLine())!=null) {
            Operation op = new Operation(operation);
            op.execute(player);
        } 
        in.close();     
    }
}
```

I can't find why it throws the NullPointer, and also I can't get the pom to stop complaining about having no main class attribute even if I set it manually. The code files tree is as follows:
[image: code source tree]

Comment: "*it looks like Main.java is actually being called*": No. Your stack trace shows: The `main` method in your `Principal.java` is called.

Comment: The part `("src/main/resource/Repository.tsv")` looks wrong cause it assumes having a file system...but running that means you are inside a JAR and then the location is simply wrong...

Comment: I don't have a Principal.java class, what is exactly calling then?? Regarding the path to the repository, I'll try to change it when I get to my computer. Thanks for the insigh to the both of you :)

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the path to accept an external attribute and it still shows the same error.